# WP7 Reminder functionality - workaround for two-weekly interval?

Tags: windows-phone-7, alert, recurrence

I am developing an app for WP7 and need to put out reminders.

The Reminder class and associated functionality is ideal... but the RecurrenceType that I can set does not include fortnightly.  It includes a handful of options including Weekly, Monthly and Yearly.

I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts to work around this?  If I have to generate multiple reminders for those events that occur fortnightly its going to become difficult  to  manage and, I am going to create an excessive number.  Also have to handle how far in the future I generate them.

It seems a shame that there are not more options available in terms of the recurrence interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot of people trying to create applications that adds a lot of reminders. And mind you, the limit of reminders are 50 per application.

But I don't really get why? Recurring events are something that belongs in a calendar feed.

I would design a application like this to work up against a iCal feed, like integration with the Windows Live calendar, or similar, and then add the events in that. And I know that at least that Google Calendar supports recurring events.

I would suggest you re-think the goal with your application. Or explain it here, so people can give better input.

There's no strait forward technical solution to this. Only hacks. So it's better to try solve the problem from a completely different angle.

Comment: Hi Claus - I am writing a WP7 Timetable app...primarily to upskill in C#/.NET/Silverlight.   Interesting because, when my son decided to wtite a Timetable app for iphone I was dubious (because I couldn't see the need for one with the standard calender functionality available.  But his app  has been very successfull, so it has spurred me on to do something similar for WP7. Hence the reason behind my query here.  He has exactly the same issue for ioS.     Thanks for your input - appreciate it. - Peter